# Doubt about a statement in Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis

> This is in Rudin's *RCA* Page 108, Section 5.22.

**Notations:**

Let $K$ be a compact Hausforff space and $H$ a compact subset of $K$. Let $A$ be the subspace of $C(K)$ such that $1\in A$, where $1$ denotes the the function that assigns the number $1$ to each $x\in K$, and such that $\| f\|_K=\|f\|_H$ for all $f\in A$, here $\|f\|_K=\sup\{f(x):x\in K\}$ is the supremum norm.

Here is the proposition:

> If $f_1,f_2\in A$ and $f_1(y)=f_2(y)$ for all $y\in H$, then $f_1=f_2$; to see this, put $f=f_1-f_2$.

My attempt is as follows: If $f=f_1-f_2$, then for each $x\in K$ we have $|f(x)|\le\|f\|_H=0$, hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in K$.

My question is, if we put $f=f_1-f_2$, how do we deduce that $f\in A$? If we want to apply $|f(x)|\le\|f\|_H$, it must be shown that $f\in A$. However I don't think $f\in A$ actually holds for all $f_1,f_2\in A$.

Comment: $C(K)$ consists of maps $K\to \mathbb R,$ so it doesn't make sense to say the identity map is in $C(K),$ since the identity is a map $K\to K.$ Maybe you mean the ring identity in the ring $C(K)?$

Comment: Since the title attributes something to Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (which many of us still have a copy of), it would make sense to add a page or chapter citation in the body of your Question.

Comment: I have made an edit to the question. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: $A$ is supposed to be a **linear** subspace of $C(K)$. Just apply your argument  to $f=f_1-f_2$.